# Apps script integrate with Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'd like to integrate google apps script with drive, specifically add my app script app to the 'create' menu in the drive, like this:

https://developers.google.com/drive/about-sdk#create_and_open_files_directly_from_the_drive_ui

It is explained a little bit in this IO video but I don't quite get the part about adding to menu.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0HVJMIeb3aE

Thanks!!!

Comment: IO video seems to go through all the details you need. Could you give better details of where in the video you find it difficult to understand?